# Using Gradle plugin to delete files and folders

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I'm using this plugin for my Gradle: https://gradle-ssh-plugin.github.io/

I've added a new task called `delete` which is supposed to delete certain folders and files. So I wrote the following:

```
task delete {
    ssh.run {
        session(remotes.web01) {
            execute 'cd /var/www/html/; rm -rf *'
        }
    }
}
```

But this wouldn't do anything. When I execute `./gradlew delete`, it will just say

```
:delete UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 4.367 sec
```

I can't seem to figure out why my folders and files are not being deleted. Just to make sure my session run was okay, I ran `execute 'cd /var/www/html/; mkdir test'` instead of what I originally had and it *did* create a folder called "test". And after putting some files in there, when I replaced the execute command with `execute 'cd /var/www/html/; rm -rf test'`, it did delete the folder properly.

I made sure that all the folders and files' are both readable and writable.

Any idea what I'm supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're executing the ssh actions during the configuration phase rather than the execution phase. The task should be defined as

```
task delete << {
    ssh.run {
        session(remotes.web01) {
            execute 'cd /var/www/html/; rm -rf *'
        }
    }
}
```